# EXCEL - SUMIFS up 2 dimensional range

Tags: excel, sum, range, sumifs

I'm trying to sum up a range of columns AND rows in EXCEL/*

Trivial Data example:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Colour | Size | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |
| red | S | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| red | M | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| green | M | 4 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| geren | L | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| blue | S | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Desired Outcome:

| Color | Small | Medium/Large |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 3 | 9 |
| green | 0 | 18 |
| blue | 6 | 0 |

I've tried for the red/small box:

=SUMIFS(C2:F5, A2:A5, "red", B2:B5, "S")

but it's returning a #VALUE error.

If the sum range is C2:C5 it works and returns a 1 but:

1. I need all the columns
2. The order of the rows is HIGHLY variable
3. The number of columns is controlled by a variable so I actually have an INDEX in there that I've excluded from this because it would just confuse things.

How can I get this to work?

/* I have inherited this process and I'm not allowed to use anything fancier than EXCEL formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to `SUMPRODUCT` in such cases:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5="red")*(B2:B5="S")*C2:F5)`

Or even just `SUM`:

`=SUM((A2:A5="red")*(B2:B5="S")*C2:F5)`

though the latter may require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, depending on your version of Excel.